# Analytics API v3 | Error 401 (Invalid Credentials) Only On A Few Accounts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-analytics-api, http-status-code-401

## Hey

I work for a marketing agency and I've developped a small script in Google AppScripts that pulls data from my customers' Analytics accounts and formats it into a Google Slides presentation.

**How it works:**

Our customers give us access to their Analytics views, and using Analytics API I get the id of each view shared with us on our main account and use these ids to make requests to the API.

The script works perfectly fine for almost every view, but recently I've had  issues with some Analytics accounts.

Basically I get a **401 response code**, despite having manager access to the given property.

The method I use to make requests to the API is ***Analytics.Data.Ga.get***, and here is what the result looks like :

```
[18-10-23 06:57:02:128 PDT] {totalsForAllResults={ga:users=0},  totalResults=0, 
columnHeaders=[{columnType=DIMENSION, dataType=STRING, name=ga:userGender}, 
{columnType=METRIC, dataType=INTEGER, name=ga:users}], 
profileInfo={profileName=Toutes les données du site Web, accountId=xxxxxx, 
profileId=xxxxxx, tableId=ga:xxxxxx,
webPropertyId=UA-xxxxxx-x, internalWebPropertyId=xxxxxx}, itemsPerPage=1000,
kind=analytics#gaData, query={end-date=2018-09-30, max-results=1000,
start-index=1, ids=ga:174758787, start-date=2018-07-01, metrics=[ga:users],
dimensions=ga:userGender}, containsSampledData=false,
id=https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?ids=ga:xxxxxx&dimensions=ga:userGender&metrics=ga:users&start-date=2018-07-01&end-date=2018-09-30, selfLink=https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?ids=ga:xxxxxx&dimensions=ga:userGender&metrics=ga:users&start-date=2018-07-01&end-date=2018-09-30}
```

When I go to that link "id" link, here's what I get :

```
{"error":
    {
    "errors":[
      {
        "domain":"global",
        "reason":"required",
        "message":"Login Required",
        "locationType":"header",
        "location":"Authorization"
      }
    ],
    "code":401,
    "message":"Login Required"
    }
}
```

I gathered this has to do with the OAuth2 protocol, which I never had to worry about since it's usually automatically handled by AppScripts.
I've looked around pretty much everywhere trying to fix the problem myself, but I can't seem to wrap my head around the OAuth 2 protocol, and the way it works in this very case.

I've already created credentials for my script, so I have access to my client id and client secret for this project.

My assumption is that the tokens for the problematic accounts have expired, and I need to refresh them somehow and give them the right scope. I just have no idea how to do that.

I would be very thankful if anyone could enlighten me on this one :)

Have a nice day!!

Comment: You can and should properly insert the example JSON and the error message in the body of your text. Images are not indexed for text, which means you don't get the best related questions nor can others find your question when searching their error text. Use your scripts Stackdriver logging capability to get the response JSON.

Comment: Just a guess but your customers may have revoked access to their data. If that's the case then your script is no longer authorized to access information on their behalf.

Comment: @tehhowch Done, thank you :)

DimuDesigns, I did check for that and it appears I still have access. Thanks for your help though:)

Comment: @GuillaumeEouzan You should format that content - a giant scroll is not exactly easy to look at.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the problem, turns out it has nothing to do with the OAuth2 protocol. The demographics reports were simply turned off in Analytics for these accounts, which is why I wasn't getting any response from my query.

If anyone is wondering, the error 401 in the REST request is because no token or key is passed at the end (using "?key=..." or "access_token=..."), so it's like some anonymous person tried to access the data.

If you wonder how to get the acess token, you can get it token using [Query Explorer](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/). After running a query, select "*Include current access_token in the Query URI (will expire in ~60 minutes)*."

Anyway, this can be closed.